# Laravel 5.3 multilanguage locale doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, localization, locale

I need to add another language to a laravel project, I did all the translation files and changed all the text to  `{{trans()}}`. I just can't change the URIs to seLocale so I wrote this route

```
   Route::get('/changelanguage', function(){
      if(Session::has('locale'))
      {
        $lang = Session::get('locale');
          if ($lang == 'en') {
              App::setLocale('ar'); 
              session(['locale' => 'ar']);
             }
          elseif ($lang == 'ar') {
             App::setLocale('en'); 
              session(['locale' => 'en']);
             }
        }else{
        session(['locale' => 'en']);
       }
     return Redirect::back();

    });
```

and this doesn't make any changes to the local

Comment: did you use trans() correctly `{{trans('file.messageKey')}}` ??

Comment: yes, the translation works when I manually change App locale to "ar"

Comment: Try to use `put` like this `Session::put('locale', 'ar');` instead of `session(['locale' => 'ar']);` !

Comment: I tried. I also tried to var_dump(App::getLocale()) and it shows an array of two strings  en & ar

Comment: Take a look to this [exampe](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-to-setlocale-in-laravel-5-on-multilingual-multidomain-app?page=1)  it creates a middleware to handel that hope that helps.

Comment: this example doesn't show how the middleware gets the user request and also the example he attached in github is different.
the point is when I redirect to a certain uri or page it works and when I leave this page the app changes back to default locale @Maraboc

Comment: Yes, in the Github example it's a job hwo change local not the middleware :p, i think the best is to do like `omar.makled` did in the same [Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-to-setlocale-in-laravel-5-on-multilingual-multidomain-app?page=1) it's well documented !

Comment: hi @BeshoyTamry, do have any tutorial that shows step by step how to setup a multi-language feature in Laravel? I am trying to follow the docs but I can't do nothing.